# How are transaction fees determined for bulk sends?

Tags: transaction

I have a use case where I want to send to many addresses on a regular basis.

Let's say I want to send to 1 million addresses. I've read that Cardano enforces a "minimum transaction fee." But is this fee applied to each recipient address in a bulk transaction? Or is it for the overall transaction?

If it's the case where I pay a fixed fee per bulk send, what is the maximum number of addresses I can send to in one bulk transaction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The minimum fee is for the transaction as a whole, calculated as `a * size(tx) + b`, where `a` and `b` are protocol parameters. However, there is a `Min-Ada-Value` of `1 ADA` which is the minimum size of a UTxO. The maximum possible UTxO set of Cardano is actually 45 billion for this reason. Anyway, you'd need to send 1 ADA per UTxO (which can be in the same transaction) and then the only limit should be the size of the transaction being less than the size limit of a block.

You can read more about this here:

Docs:
https://cardano-ledger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/explanations/min-utxo.html

Implementation:
https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger-specs/blob/master/shelley-ma/impl/src/Cardano/Ledger/ShelleyMA/Rules/Utxo.hs

Answer (score 3):

> Let's say I want to send to 1 million addresses. I've read that
> Cardano enforces a "minimum transaction fee." But is this fee applied
> to each recipient address in a bulk transaction? Or is it for the
> overall transaction?

As Edd, already mention in his post, a protocol parameter `minUtxoValue` is in place to make sure the dust is causing the UTXO to grow too much. Right now it is set to `1 ADA`.

> If it's the case where I pay a fixed fee per bulk send, what is the maximum number of addresses I can send to in one bulk transaction?

There is no maximum number of addresses per transaction directly, but this is limited by the protocol parameter `maxTxSize` which is right now set to `16384` bytes, which dictates how large in size one transaction can be. So, it all depends on your usage of addresses, number of inputs, number of outputs etc.